# How to check string text with OR logic using COUNTIF function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Goal:**
If possible I want to simplify the following statement. The functionality is to count data that has a status called "Finished A" "Finished B" or "Finished C." And the reference for $K$2 is referring to a cell with a particular date.

For example, if Finished A had 3, Finished B had 2, and Finished C had 4, then the total count would be 9. That's the calculations.

```html
=COUNTIFS('Data'!$D$4:$D,"Finished A",'Data'!$G$4:$G,"="&$K$2) + 
COUNTIFS('Data'!$D$4:$D,"Finished B",'Data'!$G$4:$G,"="&$K$2) + 
COUNTIFS('Data'!$D$4:$D,"Routed C",'Data'!$G$4:$G,"="&$K$2)
```

**Challenge:**
This particular example above is quite simple so it's manageable and if I need to make any changes, it's not going to be a problem. However if there are more criteria, then it would gets very long and difficult to read and manage. So if there's a way to shorten the above, it would be great. In the above case, I think there could there a way to combine the different statuses by using the OR logic (ex. |).

There was a case where I used "|" symbol to make an OR logic when using the Query function, however it didn't work with the Countifs functions.

**Question:**
Is there a way to do something like the following?

```html
=COUNTIFS('Data'!$D$4:$D,"Finished A|Finished B|Finished C",'Data'!$G$4:$G,"="&$K$2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,{"A","B","C"},$B$2:$B,$D$2)))
```

[image]